# How should I set a range parameter that can be also a single input in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to use

1. `CHECK_NO BETWEEN '&From_Check_No_' AND '&To_Check_No_'`
2. `CHECK_NO >= '&From_Check_No_' AND (CHECK_NO <= '&To_Check_No_' OR '&To_Check_No_' IS NULL)`
   but that can't show the appropriate results when I only input through FromNumber.
   Like range input-

> ```
> From_Check_No_: 3
> To_Check_No_: 9
> ```

result:

```
|CHECK_NO |
-----------
|    3    |
|    4    |
|    6    |
|    9    |
```

Like single input-

```
From_Check_No_: 3
To_Check_No_: (null)
```

result:

```
|CHECK_NO |
-----------
|    3    |
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the same value in the `@From_Check_No_` as `@To_Check_No_`.

```sql
DECLARE @From_Check_No_ int = 3;
DECLARE @To_Check_No_ int = 3;

SELECT CHECK_NO
FROM YourTable
WHERE CHECK_NO BETWEEN @From_Check_No_ AND @To_Check_No_;
```

Note that I say *parameters*, you should always parameterize your query rather than injecting values into it.